# Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed but no key created

Tags: mysql

I tried creating the following table using this SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `userName` TINYTEXT NOT NULL ,
  `email` TINYTEXT NOT NULL ,
  `password` LONGTEXT NOT NULL ,
  `activation` LONGTEXT NOT NULL ,
  `reg_date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

But this gives me the following error:

> 1005 - Can't create table `users` (Errcode: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

I searched around for similar questions but those queries all try to **create** a foreign key while I don't want one for this table. I do have some in my database but they don't reference this table because it doesn't exist (yet).

I did delete a foreign key in my database, but why should this interfere with creating a table.

Comment: Does the table `users` was deleted previously, some another table has a reference to it, and foreign key check was disabled before delete?

Comment: @Akina yes, the `users` table was deleted previously and referenced `userInfo`. But this table doesn't have the foreign key anymore.

Comment: What does `SELECT *
FROM information_schema.key_column_usage
WHERE 'users' IN (table_name, referenced_table_name);` return?

Comment: @JobCurtis nothing

Comment: Drop referenced column from `userInfo` structure. If its data needed, insert temporary column, copy data into it, drop original column,rename temporary.

Comment: @Akina I dropped the column and tried to create the table, but I still get the error.

Comment: If so the constraint still exists somewhere. You must find and kill it.

Comment: @Akina I don't know what's going on right now. I dropped the column (didn't work), then I dropped the whole table (didn't work), and then I deleted the whole database and it still doesn't work to create the `users` table.